# Puppeteer page.waitForNavigation() times out

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am having some difficulties using puppeteer to click a button and navigate to the next page. Whenever I run the program, it times out and gives me: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded. My program currently just inputs an address into ubereats.com and clicks the Find Food button.

I am already using

```
await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click("#wrapper > main > div.ao.ap.aq.ar.af > div.ag.bq.br.bs.bn > div > button"),
    ]);
```

When I tried the same code (with different selectors) on google.com it works. When I ran it with headless set to false, it showed the typing in of the address and scrolling to centre on the button, but nothing happened afterwards. It worked when I manually clicked on the button. I have also tried it with all the different waitForNavigation options. Any guidance would be very helpful! Thanks in advance.

The full code for reference:

```
async function scrapeProduct(url, address) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.type("#location-typeahead-home-input", address);
    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click("#wrapper > main > div.ao.ap.aq.ar.af > div.ag.bq.br.bs.bn > div > button"),
    ]);
    await page.screenshot({path: "test.png"});

    browser.close();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like clicking the button doesn't cause navigation, but unless you share the url, that's all anyone can tell you.

Answer (score -1):

```
  await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle0',timeout:0});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25784214)

Comment: //  use waitFor(milisecond);